# Looking for Author of a book I cannot find I believe was called "X/Y"

Tags: story-identification, sexuality

I need help identifying the Author of a book I used to have that I really need for research. The book I believe was called "X/Y", paperback with a mainly white cover and purple writing on the front.

Basically the story is about a  wealthy older man who switches bodies in a freak accident (or whatever) with a stripper, who has an abusive boyfriend. The stripper, in the man's body never wakes up and is in a coma...and he eventually dies. The man is furious that he is now trapped in a woman's body, and cannot get out. Eventually as the story progresses he begins psychologically abusing the boyfriend of the stripper, physically harming him as well.

It sounds messed up, but it was very well written and quite entertaining. I just hate not remembering who the author was!!! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @anaranjada Jonah, not Jason :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor whoops... well, GypsyMissy seems to have disappeared anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [X,Y](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2246182.X_Y)?:

[image]

There is a stripper:

> Frankie watched herself in the mirror as she danced in the strip
>   joint--it was the only way to get through the act. But then the fat
>   man came into the club, and the siren screamed, and Frankie's world
>   shattered like a thousand shards of glass.

And indeed, according to the blurb, the wealthy man starts to abuse the performer's boyfriend:

> Frankie, trapped and livid, slowly learns to live as a captive in a
>   woman's skin, and learns to rule over her poor lover. She makes him
>   work for her. She makes him wait on her. She uses her stranger's body
>   to torture him with his own desire.

**The author is Michael Blumlein.**